# How to restart monkeyrunner connection?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Im having problems with my monkeyrunner. The first run will work but the succeeding wont. It will just hang and say "Monkeyrunner wake command"

I am thinking that restarting the connection might fix the issue. Is there any way to restart the monkeyrunner connection?

Comment: Could you please post the part of code which you suspects ?

Comment: Hi @Rilwan , I figured that the reason why it script hangs is because I cannot initiate connection in the same device multiple times. What I did is remove MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10, devID) inside the loop. and that solved the problem. Thank you for answering the question in my other post :)